# Delayed Class Selector Call

Tags: ios, objective-c, selector, delay, class-method

I'm attempting to have a class method called with args on a delay, asynchronously, to hide a UILabel. Essentially, the label should appear, and then disappear in three seconds. I'm using the below to accomplish this.

Main method setting up the displayed view

```
 +(void)queueError:(UILabel*)messageView errorText:(NSString*)errorText{
        [messageView setText:errorText];
        messageView.hidden = NO;
        messageView.tag = arc4random_uniform(UINT32_MAX);
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^(){
            messageView.alpha = 1.0;
        }completion:^(BOOL finished){
            NSArray* args = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:messageView, [NSNumber numberWithInt:messageView.tag ], nil];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                [[UBSNavigationUtils class] performSelector:@selector(dequeueErrorTime:) withObject:args afterDelay:3];
            });
        }];
    }
```

Method to be called after three second delay

```
+(void)dequeueErrorTime:(NSArray*)args{
    UILabel* messageView = args[0];
    NSInteger tag = [((NSNumber*)args[1]) integerValue];
    if(messageView.tag == tag){
        [[UBSNavigationUtils class] fadeOutError:messageView];
    }
}
```

However, my method is never being called.

Comment: How did you figure it is not called? Did you put a breakpoint in the method to check or just your UILabel does not hide? Are you performing the fadeOut/hide on the main thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `dispatch_async`, consider `dispatch_after`.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [UBSNavigationUtils dequeueErrorTime:args];
});
```

**Edit**: I just wanted to help you clean up your code. :(

```
+(void)queueError:(UILabel*)messageView errorText:(NSString*)errorText{
  [messageView setText:errorText];
  messageView.hidden = NO;
  NSInteger expectedTag = arc4random_uniform(UINT32_MAX);
  messageView.tag = expectedTag;
  [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^(){
    messageView.alpha = 1.0;
  } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      [UBSNavigationUtils dequeueErrorMessage:messageView tag:expectedTag];
    });
  }];
}

+ (void)dequeueErrorMessage:(UILabel *)messageView tag:(NSInteger)tag {
  if(messageView.tag == tag) {
    [[UBSNavigationUtils class] fadeOutError:messageView];
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about that. I hit save before I was finished thinking.

Comment: Oh. No problem. That works perfectly for what I'm after.

Answer (score 2):

You put selector in the dispatch_queue runloop (technically as a timer), that isn't running. Therefore your method never called. I think, if you try invoke `[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]run];` , method will get called.

From apple discussion about `performSelector:afterDelay:`
When the timer fires, the thread attempts to dequeue the message from the run loop and perform the selector. It succeeds if the run loop is running and in the default mode; otherwise, the timer waits until the run loop is in the default mode.